# iOS - Is there any way of getting a Low Memory Warning in a Static Library?

Tags: ios, memory-management, static-libraries

I'm writing a static library, and I'd like to subscribe to the

```
UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification
```

notification. The issue is this notification belongs to UIApplication.h, which isn't included in my project. So I have no way of receiving a low memory warning, since all my classes are extensions of NSObject.

Any ideas?

I've checked out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MemoryAlloc.html) for Memory Management, and none of the 3 options will work (at the very bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` is the correct approach for you to take. You will need to import the `UIApplication.h` file in order to (safely) complete your library. If you're compiling for multiple architectures (iOS & OS X) then you can put conditional sections into your code so that the import isn't included when it isn't appropriate. You can also weak link `UIKit`.